# Doxxing users on the Dark Web

Tags: science-fiction, computers, internet, hacking

I'm not a hacker, but one idea has intrigued me. Imagine the story is set in a contemporary version of our modern world, and the main character is a brilliant hacker who wants to create a virus that basically doxxes anybody that peruses through the Deep Web, no matter how skilled they are in keeping themselves hidden or what kind of VPN they use. Whoever is not on an intranet while on any Deep Web sites will have their computers accessed and all their private information out there.

Could this theoretically be possible? Or is this implausible?

Comment: If you want something like this to be possible in you world it can be. If you want this to be impossible it will be. Such is the nature of creating your own world.

Comment: I don't think it will work like that. He will have to attempt to access those computers 1 by 1 otherwise large scale stuff, I'm no expert, will be stopped by anyway antivirus or firewall. And most people who use the DW would have them, if not a vpn and more.
You also seem to assume that the DW is like 2 sites.
Most of it needs special search engines and even then many sites are still invite only. He won't try a billion address combination.
Also upload speed is slower. So if he wants my titties collection he will have to wait an eternity to get.
Lastly. Storing the date is a hassle.

Comment: For even an attempt I would recommend he takes a page out of the NSA's book.
Compromise the ISPs and encryption protocols themselves. 
Imagine him working for 20 in the largest 3 ISPs in a country.
During that time he implemented "sneaky" codes an all sort of tricks so that he can benefit from that later. Though once it's patched that's it.
And tbh I would believe the companies to be so stupid to not notice.
Anyway instead of going after the stray of the herd, box in the herd and drive to a pen.
Congrats you domesticated your first I mean you hacked lots of people.

Comment: Lastly it seems stupid and arbitrary. If he wants to do something like that. 
He can target a few people or companies or so on.
But attempting to target all DW users is stupid and time consuming.
I tried it just for fun and it's boring anyway.
I would guess that good old hacking would make him more money, if it's the goal.
I'm sure the actual experts will say detailed reasonable points.

Comment: @Seallussus Considering that some journalists and people, who don't want their authoritarian (CHINA) governments to spy on them, also use the Deep Web; such hacking action could get many innocent people killed.

Comment: I agree with this Q's closure. It's story-based. All things basically follow a simple rule: where there's a will, there's a way. Nothing digital is or can be perfectly protected. In the end, it's always the defender's software vs the attacker's software. The best software wins. Which makes @sphennings absolutely correct. However, your plot is, if you'll forgive me, boring. Godlike characters are usually 2-dimensional. Besides, if this ever did happen, it would be Hacker Joe vs the entire dark web. There's a lot of hate on the DW and some pretty smart people. I'd hate to piss them off.

Comment: @JBH If you haven't studied cyber security in depth, then in may seem like a plot question, but no, this is very much a valid reality check question.  Many stories include universal computer hacks as plot hooks, but that does not make them  realistic or plausible.  It is not "the best software wins" rather it is "is the attack designed to defeat the defense".

Answer (score 5):

### You can not catch all of them

The Dark Web is does not work on a common architecture. Hacking by its very nature means exploiting a specific weakness in specific systems; so, trying to treat a group of systems that has no common architecture as a single target does not work.

Even looking at the most common defense stack, this is unlikely. If they use a TOR combined with a cross-non-extradition proxy (a common feature of VPNs), then it becomes impossible, to have access to enough of a data stream to tell who you are communicating with. No government, ISP, no one has the access to enough data to even have the building blocks to figure it out. And, if you were to gain full control of every ISP in the world to get the building blocks, then you would not have the internet capacity to do this.  You would have to multiply the internet traffic of the whole world exponentially trying to assemble all the pieces of traffic.  In this already very unlikely scenario, you would DDOS the entire world's internet long before you could DOXX the whole dark web.

### ... but you can get some of them...

The way government agencies spy on dark web users is not by breaking any specific defenses, but by creating traps that lure in dark web users.   The two most common traps are fake dark web sites that they control and by establishing Tor Endpoints of thier own. If you control the specific endpoint that a dark web user just so happens to be using, then you can send the user a virus that will compile on the other side of the broken up and encrypted stream of data.  99% of the time that virus will still either be fed fake user information or be blocked by one of many possible antivirus suites, but if you assume your genius hacker HAS come up with a new hack that can get around most defenses, then you will probably have a window of anywhere from a few days to a few months where your endpoints can DOXX the small handful of dark web users that you have targeted.

### ... in theory, you could even get a lot of them ...

Another theoretical attack vector would be to infiltrate a common dark web utility such as Onion.  If you gained access to something like this, then you could hit a LOT of targets by including spyware directly into a software patch.  Since many Dark Web users use Onion, and non-dark web users typically don't use it, that would probably be the best attack vector you could choose.  It would not hit the whole Dark Web, but you could uncover a lot of dark web users by hacking thier update system.  Because Onion is already installed on thier machines, it's access to system resources will already be validated; so, antivirus software is much less likely to flag new behaviors from it as malicious.  Since Onion is already a browser, all it has to do is wait for you to visit a website that has your real information (like your bank for example).  Then it can transmit that data directly to a command-and-control server where you will build your repository of Dark Web users until you are ready to release said information.

You could also collect browsing history this way; so, instead of just DOXXing dark web users as a whole, you could identify who is specifically using the Dark Web to engage in illegal activities such as human trafficking, hiring assassins, purchasing drugs, and child pornography.  This way, you can spare the identities of people who use the Onion for non-malicious activities like political dissenters, CEHs, and overly cautious teenagers. This way you don't have to burn the weeds with the wheat.

That said, hacking the update system for Onion is probably a few orders of magnitude harder than hacking your average government agency.  Your best bet would probably be to bribe or extort one of thier existing developers to include the hack for you... or to make your main character one of the foundering members of Onion or rather your fictional world's equivalent product since you probably don't want to run afoul of any trademark/libel lawsuits.